# Search for a keyword in a user's tweets

Tags: pandas, api, twitter, tweepy

Whenever I run the code below, it gives me the most recent 10 tweets from `@Spongebob`, instead of giving me the tweets that include "`Bikini Bottom`" from the last 10 tweets. How do I make it conditional to the keyword?

```
user = api.get_user('SpongeBob')
public_tweets = api.user_timeline("Bikini Bottom", count=10, screen_name = "SpongeBob")
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: Hi @Evie: I just took a look at the docs for [`api.user_timeline`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) and I don't see a filter argument like the one you describe - can you explain why you expect putting "Bikini Bottom" to filter the tweets?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Twitter Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), with the correct [search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators).

In this case, you want to search for the string "`bikini bottom from:spongebob`"

With Tweepy, this will be:

`public_tweets = api.search("bikini bottom from:spongebob")`